# Who would come off worst?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I'm reading the novel *[*Me Before You*](http://www.readromancebook.net/books/Me_Before_You/53.html)*. The male hero Will is a handicapped people. Now, the travelling agent was persuading Will's nursing assistant - Lou - to go to Florida.

> ‘They accommodate everyone. Why don’t you try Florida, Miss Clark? If
>   you don’t like it you could go on to SeaWorld. And the weather is
>   lovely.’
>
> ‘In Will versus killer whale I think I know who would **come off worst**.’

I can't understand the precipitate **come off worst**.
After looked it up, I nearly half understand it -

> Fare in a specified way in a contest.

But I still can't understand the sentence under this situation.

Why would she say that? And, according her meaning - "I know who would ...", Who would come off worst (I don't know)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you understand **come off**: *to fare in a specified way in a contest*, which means something like "to experience a particular result or outcome in the contest".

**Worst** is a pretty simple word, that means what it says in the dictionary: most bad, or more bad than anything else

So "to come off worst" means "to experience the worst outcome in the contest" - that is, to lose.

The context is that SeaWorld has killer whales.  So the sentence could be paraphrased as

> "If I think about the contest 'Will versus killer whale', I know who would lose."

Since Will is handicapped, presumably Will would lose to the killer whale.  Presumably the assistant is making a joke about why Will should not go to SeaWorld.